# EJS: app.set('views', viewsPath) has no effect

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Dependencies:

```
"ejs": "^3.1.9",
"express": "^4.18.2",
```

My folder structure is the following:

```
/usr/src/app/
 |
 |- app.js
 |- api/routers/main.js
 |- website
    |- src/views/myView.ejs
    |- routers
       |- main.js
       |- root.js
       |- resources.js
```

In app.js I set up EJS like so:

```
import webRouter from './website/routers/main.js'
import apiRouter from './api/routers/main.js'

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const app = express()
const port = 80

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'website/src/views'))

app.use('/', webRouter)
app.use('/api', apiRouter)


app.listen(port, () => [
    console.log('App is listening on port ' + port)
])
```

Taking webRouter as an example, it builds a router from multiple files like so:

```
import Router from 'express'
import root from './root.js'
import resources from './resources.js'
// ...

const router = Router()

root(router)
resources(router)
// ...

export default router
```

And finally, taking a simplified root.js as an example:

```
export default (router) => {
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/myView')
    })
    router.get('/myView', (req, res) => {
        res.render('myView')
    })
}
```

At runtime the path I passed to app.set correctly resolves to /usr/src/app/website/src/views.

When the request comes through, the following exception is raised:

```
server-1  | Error: Failed to lookup view "myView" in views directory "/usr/src/app/views"
server-1  |     at Function.render (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17)
server-1  |     at ServerResponse.render (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
server-1  |     at file:///usr/src/app/website/routers/root.js:3:13
server-1  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
server-1  |     at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
server-1  |     at Route.dispatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
server-1  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
server-1  |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
server-1  |     at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
server-1  |     at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
```

It looks like EJS completly ignored my app.set directive and defaulted to /usr/src/app/views.
Am I missing something?

I already tried swapping app.set('view engine') with app.set('views') but the issue persisted.
I also tried logging app.get('views') which correctly returned the provided path, just to make sure it wasn't an express issue.

Comment: Please post the code where you import your router module `router.get('/myView',` and the code where you mount this router using `app.use()`.

Comment: @jQueeny Sure, I updated the original post

Comment: I can't see fron your code but have you imported the `path` module and the `fileURLToPath` one correctly? Eg `import * as path from 'path';` and `import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';`

Comment: @jQueeny sorry I didn't include it because as I said in the original post the path resolves correctly at runtime, anyway for me it's `import path from 'path'`, but also `import * as path from 'path'` produces the same result. `fileURLToPath` was already imported like you said

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way your building your router and that `app.set` context is not being passed to the router. You could simplify it by just having `import express from 'express'; export const router = express.Router(); router.get('/', (req, res) => { res.redirect('/myView') })` and then just import it like `import {router as webRouter} from './website/routers/main.js';`

Comment: Wild guess, but try changing `myView` to `/myView`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting path before setting ejs

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'website/src/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Comment: As I already said at the end of the post, I've already tried that with no results

Comment: Another approach is to install consolidate and set it like below

const engines = require('consolidate')

app.engine('ejs', engines.ejs)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'website/src/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

if still it does not work, then I believe you have to move views folder to the root directory where app.js lies and change the path to "./views"